# When filtering by custom tags, there is no bounty indicator or filter

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav

Using the new nav with tags in URL, I can't see the bounties indicator nor can I select bounties from the "show" filter:

> [image]

and there is definitely at least one bounty question:

[image]

---

update
after going to homepage, show all tags, click on bounties indicator then filter by favorite tags then recall my custom url the indicator is shown...

Comment: tumbleweeeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

This has been made obsolete by the new release.